# MySQL Update with a fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```
UPDATE mytable SET this = 'this' AND that = 'that'
WHERE MATCH (items) AGAINST ('item5')
```

The problem is this query will perform an `UPDATE` on every match found, instead of the desired result which is to update the first row matched.

Adding `LIMIT 0, 1` to the query results in a MySQL Syntax Error. Is there a way to do this update on the first record found using a fulltext query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**documentation of `update`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html), you can use :

```
[LIMIT row_count]
```

And not, like you did :

```
LIMIT 0, 1
```

So, in your case, your query would look like this :

```
UPDATE mytable SET this = 'this' AND that = 'that'
WHERE MATCH (items) AGAINST ('item5')
LIMIT 1
```